# Is this corruption a JS/CSS bug in stack exchange?

Tags: bug

When I scroll the 'similar questions' box the text of the items overlaps making them unreadable. See screenshot (this site) and screen cast (SO).

I keep coming across this recently. I'm using Firefox 72 (but it's been happening for a month or so, so expect some earlier version(s) too).

[image: screenshot]

[image: screencast]

Comment: @Arulkumar yes. I wonder when they'll fix it.

Comment: @artfulrobot they won't. It will be "fixed" when they'll change the design, probably in few years. Non critical bugs tend to pile up, there are hundreds, if not thousands of those. It's impossible for a small team of developers, who are busy with planned projects to begin with, to ever clear such a list.

Comment: Meanwhile I suppose they'll end up with a lot of annoyed people finding duplicate questions because users can't read the useful suggestions so end up posting a new question. Like this one.

Comment: You could help out by closing this question yourself, clicking the "that answered my question button"

Comment: @Luuklag sure, and have done (I already flagged it as duplicate, chose to do this instead of delete in case the screen cast was helpful), but that's not really the point. We have a a process now that is likely to generate duplicate questions which is not in anyone's interest and degrates the quality of the content/sites.